# How to make a full backup copy of a file on windows and linux

Tags: python, file, copy, backup

I want to make a real backup copy of a file with all the metadata that belong to it.

I was searching for lib and found [shutils](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) but it doesn't copy all the metadata.

How can I do it on linux and windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that every file system (every family ext*, fat*...) and every system has it's own metadata.

On [windows it is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- owner
- file attributes (archive, read only)
- security attributes
- sharing attributes
- maybe some locks and god knows what

On Linux it's:

- mod (`chmod 0755`, which is preserved with [tar](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?tar))
- owner
- group
- selinux context (on some systems)

There're are lot of issues for example:

- what to do if user doesn't exist
- what to do if selinux isn't enabled on the computer
- what to do if shareing is not allowed
- how to handle transition from windows to Linux (and vice versa)

Not to mention some policies which may be created by gnome in Linux, or applocker in Windows.

So to **answer your question**: there's no simple way how to backup all metadata (except binary file system copy) that would work on all system.

It's your job to handle all situations mentioned above (and some more) according to what do you really need and what you can leave to its system default.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use win32file.BackupRead and BackupWrite to copy all metadata,
alternate data streams, security descriptor, extended attributes, etc.